# Who is the woman next to Palpatine during his speech?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, when Palpatine is making his speech about transitioning the Republic to an Empire, there is a bald woman (which I think is from a non-human species) standing to his left on his hovering pulpit- anyone know who she is?

Comment: Down-voting due to lack of research. A simple good search with the terms "woman next to Palpatine" reveals the answer in seconds.

Comment: @HansOlo - You may wish to note that not everyone uses Google, and the results that you see will vary from person to person, and from language to language

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Sly Moore.**

According to the canon reference guide *Ultimate Star Wars*, [Sly Moore](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sly_Moore) was the Chief of Staff for Palpatine during the final days of the Republic, and continued to serve in an advisory capacity post-transition to the Empire. Interestingly enough, she was Force-sensitive and was aware of Palpatine's true identity as Darth Sidious.

[image: Sly Moore]

Comment: Wookieepedia is a secondary source. Can you point to a primary source that identifies her by name (hint, the Star Wars Episode III Visual Dictionary, for example; https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP6sI.jpg)?

Comment: An improved answer, but can you provide the quote rather than merely asserting that Ultimate Star Wars names her?